# Individuals in odd/even positions rearranging themselves in turns, how many steps to guarantee proper order?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

#### Problem

Consider a random-ordered line of people that are standing side-by-side facing the same direction.
The people are to reorder themselves according to age, with the youngest to the left and the oldest to the right.

The line of people will be reordered by alternating the following two steps:

- Every individual in a even-numbered position will swap places with the person to their right if that person is younger.
- Every individual in a odd-numbered position will swap places with the person to their right if that person is younger.

The algorithm will automatically stop after x number of steps depending on the number of people (n) present in the line. How many of the individual steps are required to guarantee that *n* people will be sorted i every possible case?

#### My process

For every reordering process with n > 2, the required number of steps will be n. Reordering with n <= 2 will require either 1 step or 0 steps. Here are two examples where each row represents the ordering of people ages 1-4 after each reorder (#0 means no reorder has taken place).

```
Example, n = 2

    Pos    0 1
Ages #0    2 1
Ages #1    1 2         Steps required = 1




Example, n = 4

    Pos    0 1 2 3
Ages #0    4 3 2 1 
Ages #1    3 4 1 2
Ages #2    3 1 4 2
Ages #3    1 3 2 4
Ages #4    1 2 3 4     Steps required = 4
```

This "seems" to be true for every *n* number of people above 2, meaning the answer to the question is *n*. How do I prove this, though?

Comment: @juvian If there are 4 people, it will take only 3 steps to put the youngest person in the correct spot.

Comment: you could try asking in computer science if you get no answer here